# Is it safe to use Facebook Client Access Tokens in client in React app to embed instagram

Tags: reactjs, instagram, facebook-access-token

I am using [react-instagram-embed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-instagram-embed) to embed instagram post in my React app.

To be able to use instagram I need the [Client Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/#access-tokens):

> Client Access Tokens
>
> If your app must access the oEmbed endpoint from a user agent such as
> a mobile device or web browser, your app must use a Client Access
> Token and will be subject to Client Token Rate Limits.
>
> To get a Client Access Token, sign into your App Dashboard and
> navigate to Settings > Advanced > Security > Client Token.
>
> Unlike App Access Tokens, Client Access Tokens cannot be used in
> oEmbed endpoint requests on their own, they must be combined with your
> App ID. To do this, append your token to the end of your App ID,
> separated by a pipe symbol (|):
>
> {app-id}|{client-token}

For example:

access_token=1234|5678

When I inspect my source in the browser the Facebook `app-id` and `client-token` are exposed in the client.

Is it safe and this does not cause security issues?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded is divided into two ways.

The first is to copy and embed the **blockquote** tag from the website

the second is to receive and embed the **blockquote** tag as a result through the api.

For access tokens, you must call the api from the server for delivery.